# metalsmith static site generator (with react jsx)

Tags: babeljs, reactjs, jsx, metalsmith

I really want to create static site generator using reacts jsx templates/components. Jekyll and middleman had to be hacked to allow this...

But I've discovered http://www.metalsmith.io with plugin: https://github.com/yeojz/metalsmith-react-templates

I've following so far:

```
var Metalsmith    = require('metalsmith');
var reactTemplate = require('metalsmith-react-templates');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
  .clean(true)
  .use(reactTemplate({
    directory: 'templates',
    isStatic: true
  }))
  .source('src')
  .destination('build')
  .build(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

and jsx file:

```
var React = require('react');

var Entry = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    return ();
  }
});

module.exports = Entry;
```

when I run node build.js it errors out:

```
entry.jsx: Unexpected token
```

[image]

metalsmith-react-templates example seems to be outdated hence the problems?

Tried suggestion @:

```
  4 |   render: function() {
  5 | 
> 6 |     return (<p>Entry</p>);
    |             ^
  7 |   }
  8 | });
  9 |
```

Comment: Removed my (wrong) answer. Somehow the JSX transformation errors (the specific error occurs quite often). Which version of node are you running?

Comment: @janpieter_z node is v4.2.2. but I believe I'm doing smth wrong with the plugin  https://github.com/yeojz/metalsmith-react-templates

Comment: `return ();` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling Correct. But is it valid JSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@salivan

If you're still having issues even after doing `return (<p>Entry</p>);`, it is highly possible that it's actually an issue from the `babel` compiler.

What version of `babel` are you using?

If it's version 6 and above, check that you've at least installed the `babel-preset-react` and the `babel-preset-es2015` plugins.

Comment: yep this was the issue. plugin author helped me out in git issue. he also added babel-preset-react and babel-preset-s2015 as dependencies.